# Entity Framework 6 Fails Under High Load

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am stress testing my website. It uses Entity Framework 6.

I have 10 threads. This is what they are doing:

1. Fetch some data from the web.
2. Create new database context.
3. Create/Update records in the database using Database.SqlQuery(sql).ToList() to read and Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql) to write (about 200 records/second)
4. Close context

It crashes within 2 minutes with a database deadlock exception (consistently on a read!).

I have tried wrapping steps 2-4 in a Transaction, but this did not help.

I have read that as of EF6, ExecuteSqlCommand is wrapped in a transaction by default (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx). How do I turn this behavior off?

I don't even understand why my transactions are deadlocked, they are read/writing independent rows.

Is there a database setting I can flip somewhere increase the size of my pending transaction queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt EF has anything to do with it. Even though you are reading/writing independent rows, locks can escalate and lock pages. If you are not careful with your database design, and how you perform the reads and writes (order is important) you can deadlock, with EF or any other access technique.

Comment: Shouldn't the server just queue calls it can't fulfil yet until it locks are freed so they can go again? I mean there obviously has to be some limit, but SQL Server is commercial grade, it should handle 10 threads throwing queries at it.

Comment: If they are only queries it is one thing. The OP says he is reading and writing, quite different. It doesn't take much to deadlock a database, even Oracle if (like @CharlesBurns mentioned) the less appropriate transaction type is used.

Comment: I actually expected my database to be invincible, like virtual memory is. What use is a high level abstraction of the database, EF, if I need to orchestrate how I use it to write to my DB across 200 simultaneous requests?

Comment: This is exactly the danger of not knowing what is going on for real with the database.

Comment: Did not know about lock escalation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What transaction type is being used? 
.Net's TransactionScope defaults to SERIALIZABLE, at least in my applications which admittedly do not use EF. SERIALIZABLE transactions deadlock much more easily in my experience than other types such as ReadCommitted.